# Algorithm for in-app recommendations based on user navigation history

Tags: algorithm, navigation, browser-history, recommendation-engine

Currently I'm developing a web application and I want to include in-app recommendations based on user navigation history.

It would be great if you could suggest me any simple algorithm for doing that.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-recommender1/

Comment: @Moogs This was useful information. Thanks a lot!